# How to invalidate browser cache in a web application built with angular7 and springboot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm developing a web application using springboot for the backend serving rest API and Angular7 for the frontend.

my application takes so much time to load because it has to perform a lot of processing on the server, so I decided to improve the performance by storing the cached data in order to load the page first and eventually update the data when processing ends.

This works but I'm having a problem: 
When I update data in Angular these are normally saved in my database but if I update the page I don't see the changes because the browser continues to access the old cached data rather than getting the new ones modified.

Is there a way to invalidate certain data in the browser cache when they are modified?

Springboot:

My rest controller endpoint are similar to that:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/users")
  public Iterable<User> getAllUsers(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=3600");
    return this.userService.findAll());
  }
```

My service:

```
  @Cacheable("users")
  public Iterable<User> findAll() {
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
  }
```

My angular service:

```
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`<ip>' + '/users');
  }
```

Comment: you can try to reduce the `max-age` from 3600 seconds to a reasonable value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you're caching on the server side, you can evict cache by calling method annotated with `@CacheEvict` with the key you want to evict:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "users", allEntries = true)
```

Or you can do this programmatically by using `CacheManager`:

```
@Autowired
CacheManager cacheManager;

public void evictSingleCacheValue(String cacheName, String cacheKey) {
    cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).evict(cacheKey);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot, but I still have a problem: I also use browser cache adding the Cache-Control in the response inside the controller, how can i invalidate that too?

Comment: @PatrickMazzucchetti have you tried setting key's value to `null`?

Comment: where should i set the null value?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is any changes in your server side Time-based or Content-based controls by lightweight requests.

Time-based => your can use Last=Modified in the header

Content-based => you can use Etag

please check these two links;
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers

https://www.logicbig.com/quick-info/web/last-modified-and-if-modified-since.html